# What Timer Jobs are safe to turn off for a SharePoint Development environment?

Tags: sharepoint

Our SharePoint development images are having performance problems.  One of the developers has asked what timer jobs could be disabled.  What prompted this was CPU time used by OWSTimer.EXE service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would disable none of them - they all server a purpose, be it for making sure workflows run correctly, auditing happens correctly, and "heavy"/"expensive" processes (like backups) happen at quiet times.

Having the CPU time high is not an indication of a problem though - you have the resources, so why not use them? If your users are complaining of slow speeds or you are seeing errors (timeouts in the event logs are common with SharePoint in situations where you do not have enough CPU) then you should look at scaling out your deployment.